# How to show up the div on button click which is not actually set to none in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

Im trying it with laravel. On button click I need to display the same div .
**My code:**

```
    <h6>Other features  </h6>
    <div id="add1">
    <input type="text" name="selprice" />
    <input type="submit" value="+" id="add">
    </div>
```

This is my html code.Here,when I click the button**(ie.,+)** it should show up the same div(**ie add1).**

**Script code:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#add").click(function () {
         $("#add1").show();
         });
     });
 </script>
```

This is what I have tried.

Comment: you mean duplicate div?

Comment: 1. you should fix your formatting and 2. are you aware `#add` is inside `#add1`? how could you click `#add` if `#add1` is not even visible? this makes no sense. think it through again.

Comment: add1 is already in the visible state. But I want to duplicate the same div on click

Answer (score 1):

1. if you are cloning div use class instead of id.
2. use this context to get the click element
3. use append to add the cloned div to container

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click",".add",function() {
    $("#container").append($(this).parent(".add1").clone());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=container>
  <div class="add1">
    <h6>Other features </h6>
    <input type="text" name="selprice" />
    <input type="submit" value="+" class="add">
  </div>
</div>
```

Update

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".add", function() {
    var clone =  '<div class="add1"><input type="text" name="selprice" /><input type="submit" value="+" class="add"></div>';
    
    $("#container").append(clone);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=container>
  <div class="add1">
    <h6>Other features </h6>
    <input type="text" name="selprice" />
    <input type="submit" value="+" class="add">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well descriptive. +1

Comment: It works !!But is it possible to minimize same div onclick

Comment: yes using this context like i mention above. what do you mean by minimize? @nishanthi

Comment: **https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Ld4ECMaY-ealdYdlBUYzV1NEU/view**__>I need it like this

Comment: Thankyou so much!!.But I also need to close it

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/nuu4ofwu/2/

```js
var cnt = 1;
$(document).on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function(){
 cnt++;
  var div = $(this).parent().clone();
  $('body').append(div);
  $('div:last-child').attr('id', 'add' + cnt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="add1">
  <h6>Other features  </h6>
  <input type="text" name="selprice" />
   <input type="submit" value="+" id="add" />
</div>
```

Comment: Also if required change the id of the duplicate div using div.attr('id', 'new ID')

Comment: New ID , something like 'add' + $('div[id*=add]').length + 1

Answer (score 0):

You should define another div as a template:

HTML:

```
<div id="template" style="display:none;">
      <div id="add_2">
          <h6>Other features</h6>
          <input type="text" name="selprice" />
          <input type="submit" value="+" id="add_button_number"></div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
    <script>
       $('#add').click(function(){
          var str = $('#add_2').html();
          $('#add1').after(str);
        })

    </script>
```

Comment: Make some magic in template, you should define id like that `<div id="add_a_numeric"></div>` and all item having id with suffix `_a_numeric`
You should replace all `_a_numeric` to `_a_1` .... `_a_2` in jquery after get str to add.